# Codesys v.3.5 sp18 p3 - visualistation toolbox is empty

Tags: codesys

I am starting a PLC course on my uni, The Proffesor has recorded a tutorial on how to download and start CodeSyS, so I am completly yellow about it all.
I have followed the instructions carefully but for some reason visualistian toolbox is empty. I have no items to choose from.
Can anybody help me solve this problem? I've done research in google but there was no topic that would atleast help me find a way on how to solve this.

[image: No items in vis toolbox]

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Have you checked the active categories by clicking the button with a hammer at the top of the toolbox window?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, I uninstalled and reinstalled Codesys and it worked. Hopefully this help.